# Using the IF function in Excel Powerpivot with DAX

Tags: excel, if-statement, dax

I am trying to use an if statement in excel measures for powerpivot tables. I am trying to calculate revenue per unit but I have one Product Line that calculates revenue differently than all the other Product Lines. The equation I am trying to use is =IF(tableA column = "certain Product Line", calculated revenue for PL/calculated units for PL, calculated revenue for all other PLs / Calculated units for all other PLs). For some reason I keep getting the error "Calculation error in measure, a single value for column 'PRODUCT_LINE' in table 'A' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result".

Comment: Have you tried creating a calculated field versus an if statement? Build the calculated field out then pull it as a variable into your pivot table.

Comment: I thought of that but I want only two columns in the pivot table since the point of this pivot table is to compare data from one database to another to make sure there are no differences between the two. If I do a calculated field for this single product line, I'll have three columns and it will look weird as an output.

Comment: Once you create the calculated field for example column_a, column_b, column_created(b*some other thing) you can then keep column_a, and column_created(b*some other thing), then get rid of column_b from your pivot table keeping only the two you require.

If this is not clear please provide a quick screen shot and I'll walk you through this.